# Org mode #+PROPERTY: P_ALL Values doesn't work

Tags: org-mode

I recently started using Org as my planner. While I was trying to setup PROPERTIES, I found the manual says:

> If you want to set properties that can be inherited by any entry in a file, use a line like:
>   #+PROPERTY: NDisks_ALL 1 2 3 4

So I did something like:

```
#+PROPERTY: Effort_ALL 00:10 00:30 01:00
```

on the top of my org file.

Now when I go to one of the entries and hit `C-c C-x e TAB`, it tells me "No Match".
When I try to put in the Effort property first by `C-c C-c p` and then try to use `S-TAB` on the generated Effort property, it says "Allowed values for this property have not been defined", which obviously is saying that the `#+PROPERTY` line does not exist.

I can do lines like this without any issue. That is, there's auto-completion and I can do `S-TAB` to cycle through defined values.

```
   * CD collection
   :PROPERTIES:
   :NDisks_ALL:  1 2 3 4
   :Publisher_ALL: "Deutsche Grammophon" Philips EMI
   :END:
```

A bit background info:

Windows 10 pro

Emacs 26.2 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32)

Using Org-Evil (turned it off but the problem still persisted)

Comment: Did you type `C-c C-c` on the `#+PROPERTY:` line after you entered it? Or restart emacs and reread the file? This is usually the cause of the problem in such cases.

Comment: Hi @NickD, I didn't type `C-c C-c` but did restart emacs. I'll try later see if `C-c C-c` works. Never occurred to me I needed to do that tho.

Comment: See the [Setting up keywords for individual files](https://orgmode.org/manual/Per_002dfile-keywords.html#index-keyword-options) section in the manual, although if you restarted emacs after changing the file, it should have worked (see the footnote in that section). BTW, it does work for me.