# Allowed values at #+PROPERTY header line not recognized

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to set allowed property values at the top of an org-mode cheatsheet i'm working on. Only two allowed values so far for the `CATEGORY` property. I'm getting the same "Allowed values for this property have not been defined" issue experienced in the issue linked below.

```
#+PROPERTY: CATEGORY Meta Create
...
* Org-mode essentials
:PROPERTIES:
:CATEGORY: Meta
:END:
** M-RET        - New bullet at the current level
:PROPERTIES:
:CATEGORY: Create
:END:
```

I have followed [org-mode Property documentation](https://orgmode.org/guide/Properties.html) as recommended by [the most similar question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/52512/org-mode-property-p-all-values-doesnt-work). I am running emacs 26.3 with org 9.1.9 on Linux Mint 20. I've tried reloading settings for the current file (C-c C-c) and restarting Emacs to no avail.

Is the issue in the syntax of the top line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The allowed values for a property are specified by defining a specially named property: e.g. for specifying the values for a `CAT` property, you specify the allowed values as the value of the property `CAT_all`:

```
#+PROPERTY: CAT_all Meta Create
```

Don't forget to `C-c C-c` on the property line, to refresh the buffer and inform Org mode about this new property.

Then you can use `C-c C-x p`, specify `CAT` as the name of the property and use `TAB` completion to select a value.

See the "Property syntax" section of the manual, which you can visit in Emacs with `C-h i g (org)Property syntax`.

Note: I used `CAT` for the name of your property because Org mode already has a *special* property called `CATEGORY`: `C-h i g (org)Special properties` will get you to the section that defines all of them. That section says:

> The following property names are special and should not be
> used as keys in the properties drawer.